# Fourier transform in the complex motion group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations

I am looking for a reference that deals with the unitary dual of  the complex motion group $\mathbb C^2 \rtimes SU(2)$ i.e., the semi-direct product of $\mathbb C^2$ with the special unitary group $K=SU(2)$. More precisely, a reference that defines the "group theoretic" Fourier transform on this group?

Thank you in advance